Why is the kv files in my kivy applications not working?
I was working on the pong tutorial provided by the Kivy documentation website, after making the .kv file where I implemented the centered rectangle, and the numbers(labels), I ran the code, but the screen was just black. I have looked all over youtube, and asked chatGPT, but cannot find the source of my issue. The code:
main.py:
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class PongGame(Widget):
    pass


class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return PongGame()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()

pong.kv:
#:kivy 1.0.9

<PongGame>:    
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x - 5, 0
            size: 10, self.height
            
    Label:
        font_size: 70  
        center_x: root.width / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: "0"
        
    Label:
        font_size: 70  
        center_x: root.width * 3 / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: "0"

I have checked my directory for both files, and both files are in the same folder. The names are also right, as I even copy and pasted from the kivy website and double checked. It should show 2 0s on either side of a rectangle which is centered in the middle. Also all indentations are correct for the kv and python files.

your code works for me on Linux Mint, Python 3.10, Kivy v2.2.0rc1,
